# Magento 1 - Convert Object into an array value

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-1, collection, object

I was trying to get the information of tracking in the UPS. I got on of the method from the core (`app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php` => method name `getTracking($trackings)`) that gives me the output that I want. But it's format in object form kind of as shown below.

So my question is how can I convert object in array?

```
Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result Object
(
    [_trackings:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result_Status Object
                (
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [carrier] => ups
                            [carrier_title] => United Parcel Service
                            [tracking] => 1Z90Y8A21294899248
                            [service] => UPS 3 Day Select
                            [shippeddate] => 20180910
                            [weight] => 6.00 LBS
                            [status] => Order Processed: Ready for UPS
                            [deliverydate] => 2018-09-10
                            [deliverytime] => 06:31:46
                            [deliverylocation] => 
                            [signedby] => 
                            [deliveryto] => US
                            [progressdetail] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
                    [_origData:protected] => 
                    [_idFieldName:protected] => 
                    [_isDeleted:protected] => 
                    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [_error:protected] => 
)
```

I have already tried with the getData(), also (array) $obj but that's not working giving blank responce.

Answer (score 1):

All Magento Models inherit from the Varien_Object class. Magento Models store their data in a protected _data property. The Varien_Object class gives us several methods we can use to extract this data. You will see getData, which will return an array of key/value pairs.

You can use below code to get data from object in array format

```
$array = $object->getData();
```

This will give you array of object.

Below code give you reference how you can get object data within object

```
if ($trackings = $this->_result->getAllTrackings()) {
      foreach ($trackings as $tracking){
         if($data = $tracking->getAllData()){
             if (isset($data['status'])) {
                $statuses .= Mage::helper('usa')->__($data['status']);
             } else {
               $statuses .= Mage::helper('usa')->__($data['error_message']);
             }
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Prashant,
I have already tried with he getData(), It's giving blank response.

Comment: Updated answer please check it

Comment: What will be $this->_result for me, I am getting tracking information in my custom controller?

Comment: Your object which you have var_dump

Comment: I have checked it's the code form the responce() function in the ups.php model.I am using the below code ,
$ups = Mage::getSingleton('usa/shipping_carrier_ups')->getTracking($track);
        if ($trackings = $ups->getAllTrackings()) { foreach .... }

It's showing blank page.

Comment: Please uncomment ini_set('display_error',1); in index.php file and check error

Comment: It's already uncommented and I have echo the $statuses